# How to have an attenuation different from 40/20 dB per decade with a basic filter

Tags: filter

I would like to do a theoritical filter with different attenuation according to the frequency. How can I do for having an attenuation different from 20 dB per decades. If for example I want to have an attenuation equal to 8.23 dB per decade ? How can I do ?

Have a nice day :)

Comment: You can approximate it with a series of shelving networks, like a staircase. First you need to know the frequency span of interest and the accuracy required.

Comment: There is also *fractional order filters*. But currently they can ve realised using the method mentioned in above comments.

Comment: Use a graphic equalizer.

Comment: just to be sure: this is about implementing a complicated analog filter, not about a digital one, right? Because in the analog case, as user_1818839 correctly points out, realization 100% depends on the frequency range of interest. A filter with GHz bandwidths is implemented fundamentally different than one for audio, is implemented fundamentally different than for narrowband RF.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was looking at this not long ago, as a series of steps in the bode plot, logarithmically spaced, exactly like the first comment.

Expression below will give a slope of +/- 20\${\gamma}\$ dB/decade, between \${\omega}_0\$ and \${\omega}_f\$. N is number of pole-zero pairs.

$$\displaystyle\frac{\left(1+\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^\gamma}{\left(1+\frac{s}{\omega_f}\right)^\gamma}
\space\space\space\space
\approx
\space\space\space\space
\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{N}
\frac
{ \left( 1+s\frac{ {q} ^ {(k-1) } }{ \omega_0 }  \right) }
{ \left( 1+s\frac{ {q} ^ {-(k-1)} }{ \omega_f } \right)  }
\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space
q= \left( \frac{\omega_f}{\omega_0} \right) ^{ \frac{(N-\gamma)}{N(N-1)} }
$$

I think it is equivalent to what you would get with the Oustaloup approximation for \$s^\gamma\$, which is described [here](https://www.irjet.net/archives/V3/i8/IRJET-V3I8330.pdf) for example.