# Is it possible to achieve a square root analog filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-pass, homework, active-filter

I am attempting to create a (3/2)th-order active low-pass filter circuit, with a zero[es] at ω=10000 and pole[s] at ω=100. The only way I can think to do this is to simply cascade three simple first-order low-pass inverting amplifiers, and then I would have to square root the entire expression - is this possible? Attached is a simple rundown highlighting my difficulty - the creation of H1 as described is trivial.

For context: I was given a Bode plot with a pole at ω=100 and a zero at ω=10000 and asked to create a circuit after deriving the transfer function, the catch is that there is a negative slope of -30 dB/decade instead of a usual -20 dB/decade for poles. I re-derived the Bode magnitude and phase formulae and found that, given the property of exponents within logarithms, log(m<sup>p</sup>) = p·log(m), I could tweak the slope of the zero/pole asymptotes. I just can't realize it physically yet.

[image]

Comment: An RC transmission line has a characteristic impedance of sqrt(R/jC). You can use that to make a half order filter.

Comment: @John Doty - like a ladder filter with RC sections? Or is there another way to realize such a thing?

Comment: For a formula to synthesize an approximation (arguably more useful in digital domain): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/569912/how-to-have-an-attenuation-different-from-40-20-db-per-decade-with-a-basic-filte/570022#570022

Comment: You don't need the square root of a third order. You can leave one order alone and then follow it up with the square root of a first order.
You don't make clear what this "I was given a Bode plot with a pole at ω=100 and a zero at ω=10000" has to do with the first part. (But anyway, it's probably a homework question. Succes!)

Comment: Have you ever encountered a Laplace function with an "s" under a square root? What about the "phase"?

Comment: @PeteW A ladder, but you're using it as a sort of half capacitor, only connecting to one end.

Comment: @Antonio51 Yes, in fractional calculus this is routine, as Tim Williams points out. In practical work, sqrt(s) shows up when you're dealing with flicker noise. The phase lag of a half order fractional integrator is 45 degrees.

Comment: @Antonio51 - I've encountered it in fluid/pressure in elastic tubes, which I believe is analogous to a theoretical RC transmission line

Comment: @JohnDoty and Pete W   ... ok, I did not calculate yet.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the square root is a nonlinear operation. You must not go that route, or you tell produce intermodulation products at frequencies that weren't even necessarily present in the input signal.

So to answer the question from your title: you can create a square root system in the analog domain, but it is very certainly not the filter you are looking for.

Comment: He apparently wants a linear filter of 3/2 order. Possible in principle.

Comment: The thing he wants to take the square root of is frequency, not amplitude.

Comment: It's not a nonlinear process, but the impulse response will be a lot different. Solutions lead into the domain of fractional calculus.

Comment: @JohnDoty since the Fourier transform itself is a linear operation, a non-linear operation in frequency domain does directly correspond to a non-linear one in the time domain.

Comment: @TimWilliams note the flow chart shown: $$V_{in}\rightarrow\boxed{H_1}\rightarrow\boxed{\sqrt{\,\,}}\rightarrow$$ they are explicitly applying a square root operation, not $\sqrt{H_1}$!

Comment: @sinabala Mutiplying Fourier amplitudes by any function of frequency is a linear operation in amplitude. That function could be square root.

Comment: @JohnDoty taking the square root is not a multiplication with a function.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The square root of frequency is a function.

Comment: @JohnDoty yes, but taking the square root of a curve is not the same as multiplying the curve with a constant function $S(f)$, unless the curve is constant – and that's not the case. Formally: $$\sqrt{V_{in}(f)\cdot H_1(f)} \ne (V_{in} \cdot H_1) \cdot S(f)$$

Comment: @MarcusMüller The OP asks for a "(3/2)th-order active low-pass filter circuit", which is the description of a filter linear in amplitude. Except for pure integrators and differentiators, filters are never linear in frequency.

Comment: again, that's fine, because you multiply with them. You don't multiply with a square root function, you take the square root function of the result of a filter. The difference here is that you multiply with the filter, and you square root; two different operations.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's clear that he's not really asking for Vin to be under the radical.

Comment: @JohnDoty I mean if that's clear I **do** agree with you; it's just that I felt the text was contradictory to the picture, and that the analog approach suggested he wanted to take the square root of the frequency-domain signal

Comment: @sinabala They are multiplying in the Fourier domain, notice capital Vin, capital H. This is *convolution* in the time domain, a linear operator.

Comment: Confused here. There seem to be some people that like me think the \$\boxed{\sqrt{ \,}}\$ operation in the sketch is expected to be taken literally, , i.e. as operation on the already filtered signal continuously, and others assume it's an operation that should be applied to the frequency response once, to get the filter to actually convolve with